# Enumerate examples

Tags: numbering, enumerate, counters, examples

I want to be able to keep track of numbered examples throughout chapters/sections, something like `\section{<name>}` or maybe an environment would work better. So I could have something like

[image]

or

[image]

but without having to carefully plan out the naming so I could just say, for example

```
\example The problem (optional)
The solution
```

(Bonus points if I can specify the prefix)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You can use something like `\newtheorem{example}[chapter]`, and customise the look of the example environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same plan and got a solution:

Creating new environment look like:

```
% template for solved examples
\newcounter{examplenum}[section] % where to start, Chapter/section/subsection

\newenvironment{example}[1]{
% begin the environment
\refstepcounter{examplenum}
\noindent\textbf{Example or Ex.} \theexamplenum\hspace{0.6ex}\textit{#1}
\vspace{0.5ex}
% body of environment (the equations)
}{%
% close the environment
\hfill\(\color{blue!60}\rule{0.6em}{0.6em}\vspace{2ex}\)
}
```

Use of the template:

```
\begin{example}{Example text: 1+1}

1+1=2
\end{example}
```

You can optionally use the *Example text*.

Hope you got the idea. Lemme know for more.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Also, to note, I had to `\usepackage{color}` and replace `blue!60` with just `blue`.